# Using Redis to temporary caching files

Tags: database, caching, redis

I would like to temporary cache uploaded files in Redis. I know it is utilizing a lot of memory, but I think it is the best way to have a really low latency for a temporary amount of time.

How do I store files in Redis? Do I somehow convert them into binary and store them and decode them when I need them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings in Redis are binary safe, which means you could store binary files without any problem (https://redis.io/topics/data-types#strings).

The way you will do this depends on the language and frameworks you are using, but, generally speaking, one way to accomplish this is just storing in Redis the file content as base64.

Hope it helps.